# Remove all event listeners except for specific ones in Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have node.js app with socket.io which I use to select and load different external modules (which I call "activities") in real time.

Since every module binds it's own events to the sockets, when I change from one module to another I want to be able to remove from my sockets all the event listeners that the previous module added.

I would use [emitter.removeAllListeners()](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removealllisteners_event), but that would also remove the events I define in the server, which I do not want.

Here is how my code looks like:

`app.js`

```
// Boilerplate and some other code

var currentActivity;
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){

    client.on('event1', callback1);
    client.on('event2', callback2);

    client.on('changeActivity', function(activityPath){
        var Activity = require(activityPath);
        currentActivity = new Activity();

        // Here I'd like some loop over all clients and:
        // 1.- Remove all event listeners added by the previous activity
        // 2.- Call currentActivity.bind(aClient) for each client
    });
})
```

An example activity would be something like the following

`someActivity.js`

```
module.exports = function(){

    // some logic and/or attributes

    var bind = function(client){

        client.on('act1' , function(params1){ // some logic
        });
        client.on('act2' , function(params2){ // some logic
        });
        // etc.
    }
}
```

So, for instance in this example, if I change from `someActivity.js` to some other activity, I'd like to be able to remove for all clients the listeners for "act1" and "act2", without removing the ones for "event1", "event2" and "changeActivity".

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You could (a) keep a list of those event names by listening to the `newListener` event, or pssibly (b) get the listeners for the events you want to keep with `emitter.listeners()` for the events you want to keep, clear all else, and reattach them (never tried it, might have side effects).

Comment: @Wrikken, it seems there is no newListener event, or at least I can't find it in the docs. Got any link? For your second option, I think I would need to know in the server the name of the events in the module, causing an undesired coupling.

Comment: Well, [this page says there is](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_event_newlistener). According to [this page](http://nodejs.org/changelog.html) it's been there since 2009.08.27 Version 0.1.7.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking in the Socket.io documentation. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a method in each module called **unbind** that removes all of the listeners added by the **bind** function:

```
var fun1 = function(params1){ // some logic };    
var fun2 = function(params2){ // some logic };

module.exports = function(){    
    // some logic and/or attributes    
    var bind = function(client){    
        client.on('act1' , fun1);
        client.on('act2' , fun2);
    }

    var unbind = function(client){
        client.removeEventListener('act1',fun1);
        client.removeEventListener('act2',fun2);
    };
};
```

If you need access to the **client** in the listeners, I would refactor it to pass the client to the constructor:

```
function MyModule(client){
   this.client = client;
};
MyModule.prototype.fun1 = function(params1){
   //do something with this.client
};
MyModule.prototype.fun2 = function(params2){
   //do something with this.client
};
MyModule.prototype.bind = function(){
   this.client.on('act1' , this.fun1);
   this.client.on('act2' , this.fun2);
};
MyModule.prototype.unbind = function(){
   this.client.removeEventListener('act1' , this.fun1);
   this.client.removeEventListener('act2' , this.fun2);
};
module.exports = MyModule;
```

Then you can use it like:

```
client.on('changeActivity', function(activityPath){
    var Activity = require(activityPath);
    var currentActivity = activityCache[activityPath] || new Activity(client); //use the existing activity or create if needed
    previousActivity.unbind();
    currentActivity.bind();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of something as the first idea, but that seemed a little bit repetitive for me. Also, it depends on the module implementation, do you think there is another way to solve this where the server has control of the unbinding, without knowing the name of the events in the module?

Comment: Also, I think your refactor would work quite good, but not in my case since I want to have only one instance of the module for all of the  n clients.

Comment: The server would only need to use the bind and unbind methods, like an interface. I changed the usage to share the activity instances. I may be misunderstanding your intention. Can you show some example socket.io code?